# Quicksort: Non-in-place implementation works. In-place implementation exceeds maximum recursion depth. Why?

Tags: python, recursion, stack-overflow, quicksort

```
def quicksort_stable(l):
    if not l:
        return l
    else:
        pivot = l[0]
        return quicksort_stable([x for x in l if x < pivot]) \
                + [x for x in l if x == pivot] \
                + quicksort_stable([x for x in l if x > pivot])    

def quicksort_inplace(l):
    def partition(start_idx, end_idx):
        left_idx = start_idx + 1
        right_idx = end_idx
        while True:
            while left_idx <= right_idx and l[left_idx] <= l[start_idx]:
                left_idx += 1
            while right_idx >= left_idx and l[right_idx] >= l[start_idx]:
                right_idx -= 1

            if right_idx < left_idx:
                break
            else:
                l[left_idx], l[right_idx] = l[right_idx], l[left_idx]

        l[start_idx], l[right_idx] = l[right_idx], l[start_idx]     

        return right_idx

    def qs(start_idx, end_idx):
        if start_idx < end_idx:
            split_idx = partition(start_idx, end_idx)
            qs(start_idx, split_idx - 1)
            qs(split_idx + 1, end_idx)

    qs(0, len(l) - 1)
    return l

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import random

    l1 = [random.randint(0, 9) for x in range(10000)]
    l2 = [x for x in l1]

    l1 = quicksort_stable(l1)
    quicksort_inplace(l2)
```

I deliberately chose the first element as the pivot instead of randomizing to ensure that both implementations behave the same way.

Both implementations are implemented recursively. In the call stack, it seems like quicksort_inplace should take O(lg n) space while quicksort_stable should take O(n) space since it creates a new list every time it recurses.

Yet, quicksort_inplace is the one that causes "maximum recursion depth exceeded" while quicksort_stable works fine.

Why is this so?

Comment: Try printing the values of start_idx and end_idx inside `qs`, that should give you a clue.

Comment: Huh, is it because the small range of numbers causes quicksort_inplace to recurse on partially sorted lists every time it recurses and partially sorted lists are not good for the quicksort algorithm? quicksort_stable side steps this problem by collecting all elements equal to the pivot and doesn't recurse on that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason for this behavior is that your list contains lots of repetitions (every element appears ~1000 times), and you "cheated" implementing the *stable* version by gathering all elements equal to pivot at once and not getting back to them (which is of course great!).

So to actually compare these two procedures it should look like this:

```
    def quicksort_stable(l):
        if not l or len(l)==1:
            return l
        else:
            pivot = l[0]
            rst = l[1:]
            return quicksort_stable([x for x in rst if x < pivot]) \
                    + [pivot] \
                    + quicksort_stable([x for x in rst if x >= pivot])
```

Plus, in order to have the destructive (inplace) version of the above you should change a condition on your second while to *greater-than* (so that on right of *right_idx* there are elements no less than *pivot*), i.e.

```
        while right_idx >= left_idx and l[right_idx] > l[start_idx]:
```

If you do this you'll find that both procedures cause stack overflow on arrays with 10000 elements from *range(0,9)* (note also that with *range(0,99)* this is not the case because they require less "cuts").